# LINQ to XML: Access denied to AppData/Local

Tags: xml, linq

I'm trying to use LINQ to XML to save application logs in the users AppData/Local-folder.

When I create an xml-file from my main-application reading/writing works just fine. But, when I try to write to the Local-folder from a ClassLibrary (my log-handler), I get an "Access denied" error.

I have made sure that the

```
var log = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\MyApp\log.xml";
var xLog = new XDocument(new XElement("entries"));
xLog.Root.Add(new XElement("entry",
new XAttribute("id", newId),
                new XElement("time", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now)),
new XElement("type", type),
new XElement("text", text),
new XElement("module", module)
));
xLog.Save(log);
```

Does the ClassLibrary require some other permissions than the main-app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made a mistake in my code. The path to the local-directory, wasn't correct.

I still don't know why I got the "access denied"-error, because the path should have been recognized as a valid path...